# Change system Proxy settings using Android SDK

Tags: android, proxy, pac

I'm migrating a Google Chrome extension that I made to an Android version, but I'm facing some questions.

It is basically a Proxy server for certain websites that were blocked in my country. This is working on Chrome by changing the proxy settings with our proxy and with a PAC file that specifies which sites should be proxied.

How can I change the system proxy settings using the Android SDK? Is it doable? If not, what suggestions do you have to have this done?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after A LOT of investigation, I concluded that this is not a good idea. Also, in most recent Android versions, use an app to set a proxy is mostly impossible.

I've decided a different approach and use a VPN. It works, but is not as lightweight as I would like it to be.